# smart data of a new SSD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have bought a new SSD. Today i installed Elementary OS Linux on the SSD.
After that i install smartmontools to check the status of my new SSD.
Can you check if the Smart Attributes are safe for a new SSD,
in particular Total Lba Written 66876697

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-59-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB
Serial Number:    S2RBNB0HB53296Y
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 d41711f97
Firmware Version: EMT02B6Q
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jan 20 23:08:47 2017 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 265) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   069   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       66876697
```

Comment: if i run iostat in the command line

Comment: Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              15.72       392.40       310.25     909972     719453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
>   241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       66876697

66876697*512/1024/1024/1024 ~= 32

32GB written seems reasonable to me.

Comment: how many GB a day can I write? Samsung says 150TBW.

Comment: It depends how long you want it to last. Let's say 10 years and let's assume that the drive will blow up at exactly 150TBW (it won't). Then I get about 42GB per day. You wrote 32GB installing an OS, so you can install one and one third OSes per day for ten years with no expected issues. ;)